# How to restrict hoverEffect to a specific View within a Button when using plain button style

Tags: button, swiftui, hover, visionos

I have a Button that contains a Circle and a Text under it. I want to use the plain button style so that there's no bordered background visible initially and it scales appropriately when tapped. When hovering over it, I'd like only the Circle to display a hover effect. This appears as expected when you hover over the Circle, but when you hover over the Text the default oval button hover effect appears. How can I remove the default button hover effect and only apply one to the Circle, or otherwise restrict the hover effect to just the Circle?

```
Button(action: action) {
    VStack {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundStyle(.fill.quinary)
            .hoverEffect()
        
        Text("Title")
    }
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)
```

If I add `.hoverEffectDisabled()` to the VStack, the default hover effect still appears, and it appears even when you hover over the circle.

[image]

Comment: The `.hoverEffect` modifier is not available for macOS, so are you talking about an iOS device with assistive technology? Or how do you go about seeing the hover effect that you are describing?

Comment: This question is for visionOS @BenzyNeez

Comment: I don't know but, it seems it is working as you'd like on VisionPro. The hover effect only shows onto the Circle.

Comment: @MatBuompy when you hover over the text the hover effect is applied to the whole button not just the circle as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Put the text outside of button

Comment: @ion The entire thing should be a button, tapping the title should trigger its action

Comment: Use contentShape modifier on the Button  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentshape(_:eofill:)

Comment: How does that work @ion? Docs note it defines the content shape for hit testing, but the shape for hit testing is already correct, the only thing to customize is the hover effect